# How to prioritize background-color of most recently added class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

At the time of writing, the colors are ordered in a hierarchy where purple has the highest priority. How do I change this so that the most recently added color gets the highest priority instead? Here's my code:

```
<table id="palette">
    <tr>
        <td id="yellowPaint" class="yellow"></td>
        <td id="redPaint" class="red"></td>
        <td id="purplePaint" class="purple"></td>            
        <td id="bluePaint" class="blue"></td>
        <td id="greenPaint" class="green"></td>
        <td id="orangePaint" class="orange"></td>
        <td id="whitePaint" class="white"></td>
        <td id="blackPaint" class="black"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var color = "white";

        $('#yellowPaint').click(function(){
            color = "yellow";
        })

        $('#redPaint').click(function(){
            color = "red";
        })

        $('#purplePaint').click(function(){
            color = "purple";
        })

        $('#bluePaint').click(function(){
            color = "blue";
        })

        $('#greenPaint').click(function(){
            color = "green";
        })

        $('#orangePaint').click(function(){
            color = "orange";
        })

        $('#whitePaint').click(function(){
            color = "white";
        })

        $('#blackPaint').click(function(){
            color = "black";
        })

        $('#massiveTable td').mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).addClass(color);
        });
    });

</script>
```

And the CSS, as requested:

```
.white {
    background-color: white;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

.black {
    background-color: black;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.orange {
    background-color: orange;
}

.purple {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

You can see the result on pseudostories.com/draw

Comment: I don't understand your question? `most recently added colour gets priority`? Please clarify.

Comment: Also, can we have your css?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: That's not how CSS works.  If you want only one class to apply to an element, remove all the other classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of addClass, replace it entirely:

```
$('#massiveTable td').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).attr('class',color);
});
```

Comment: That solved the problem! Will accept answer in 4  min, when SO allows it.

Comment: Just another way: `$(this).removeClass().addClass(color)`

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the previous classes before adding the new one :

```
$('#massiveTable td').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).removeClass();
    $(this).addClass(color);
});
```